# Chainlink node error: BumpGasUntilSafe FindTxBy Attempt: record not found

Tags: oracles, chainlink

I am currently testing sending requests to my Chainlink node on Ropsten. I am following the documentation for [running a Chainlink node](https://docs.chain.link/docs/fulfilling-requests) and all went well until.

`40 BumpGasUntilSafe FindTxByAttempt: record not found.`

What is usually the cause of this error?

Comment: Please share your account address or one of transaction hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SEE!

This issue usually means that the amount of gas you are setting is not enough for your transaction to safely go through. The gas has a default value set in the [configuration variables](https://docs.chain.link/docs/configuration-variables). There are two main things you could do to fix it. The simplest solution is to run the gas-updater docker image. This connects to your node and updates the gas costs of your node's transactions to a decentralized safer value.

First, pull the docker image:

`docker pull thodges/cl-gas-updater:latest`

Then run the command:

`docker run --name gas-updater -d --restart unless-stopped -it -e CL_URL=http://172.17.0.1:6688 -e CL_EMAIL=<NODE_GUI_LOGIN_EMAIL> -e CL_PASSWORD=<NODE_GUI_LOGIN_PASSWORD> -e MAX_GAS_PRICE=500000000000 -e FALLBACK_GAS_PRICE=50000000000 -e ADD_GAS_PRICE=1000000000 thodges/cl-gas-updater`

---

You can also adjust the gas setting by changing the [configuration variables](https://docs.chain.link/docs/configuration-variables) in the `.env` config. You can check the link to see what each do, but you could set a few to what you see similar in the docker command above. For example:

`MAX_GAS_PRICE=500000000000
FALLBACK_GAS_PRICE=50000000000
ADD_GAS_PRICE=1000000000`

But having a dynamic gas updater (the `thodges/cl-gas-updater` image from above) is a much cheaper and more affective solution.

Eventually, the gas updater will be built into the node docker container.